# Which user to use with deployment keys?

Tags: gogs

I am trying to use deployment keys for a repository which belongs to an organization (for which I am an administrator).

I created a private/public key pair, the public was pasted into the 'deployment keys' window, and accepted. I then tried to connect via `git pull` from a distant repository:

```
git add origin git@myserver.com:/organization/therepo.git
git pull
```

I keep being asked for the password for the user `git`. I tried to use instead the users `git`, `gogs`, `<my login>`, `<the name or the organization>` -- I am being asked for the password every time.

I tried a simple `ssh -v` to check which key is provided to gogs: it is the right one (the private key above, corresponding to the deployment (public) key).

**Which user should I use to connect?**

Comment: I looked at some example `gogs` repo URLs. Should the forward slash before "organization" be there?

Comment: @DavidCullen: you are right, I also tried without the slash initially. Still, the authentication does not go through so this would not be the issue (I would get a `repository ... not found` kind of error)

Comment: What did you use for "Run User"? Does that account exist? If so, is that user running `gogs`?

Comment: @DavidCullen: Thanks for the update - this is a good path for troubleshooting. I checked, the user is `git`. I see that its `.ssh/authorized_keys` has the key I put via the web interface. I will try to debug the `ssh` connexion form the sever end to see how it looks like from that side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*All credit for the troubleshooting ideas goes to [David Cullen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3657941/david-cullen) (via his comments)*

The problem was that **I was calling the wrong `sshd` service**.

My GOGS service runs in docker and the `ssh` port is different from the one of the host server (which is what I was calling using the default port 22):

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
86ddbabc8cbb        gogs/gogs           "docker/start.sh /bin"   13 days ago         Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10022->22/tcp   gogs
```

By using an ~/.ssh/config file like that

```
Host    my.git.server.com
        Port 10022
        IdentityFile    /var/www/.ssh/my.private.key.openssh
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I now successfuly pull the GOGS repository from a remote server:

```
$ git pull ssh://git@my.git.server.com:/organisation/therepo
From ssh://my.git.server.com:/organisation/therepo
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

Please note that there **is** a slash before `organisation` (re: initial comments)